# "SSL certificate validation failure" when verifying wildcard server certificate in MariaDB 5.5

Tags: ssl, certificates, mariadb

I've been trying to move from using a self-signed certificate to using a wildcard certificate from a well-known CA to reduce maintenance overhead and improve security. The certificate has already been in use for months on test servers. The setup is working well enough that I can do the following (domain name anonymised):

```
mysql --host=host.example-dot-com-equivalent-for.co.uk --user=query_user --password --ssl
```

This connects successfully after providing the password. However, when I try to actually [*verify* the certificate Common Name](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/connecting-to-mariadb/#ssl-verify-server-cert) it fails:

```
$ mysql --host=host.example-dot-com-equivalent-for.co.uk --user=query_user --password --ssl --ssl-verify-server-cert
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: SSL certificate validation failure
```

After compiling MariaDB 5.5 using `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DWITH_SSL=yes` and running the client with `--debug` I get the following trace log (trimmed):

```
mysql_real_connect: info: Connecting
mysql_real_connect: info: net->vio: 0x0  protocol: 0
mysql_real_connect: info: Server name: 'host.example-dot-com-equivalent-for.co.uk'.  TCP sock: 3306
mysql_real_connect: info: IP 'client'
mysql_real_connect: info: IPV6 getaddrinfo host.example-dot-com-equivalent-for.co.uk
mysql_real_connect: info: Try connect on all addresses for host.
mysql_real_connect: info: Create socket, family: 2  type: 1  proto: 6
mysql_real_connect: info: Connect socket
mysql_real_connect: info: End of connect attempts, sock: 4  status: 0  error: 0
mysql_real_connect: info: net->vio: 0x263c540
mysql_real_connect: info: Read first packet.
mysql_real_connect: info: mysql protocol version 10, server=10
get_charsets_dir: info: charsets dir: '/usr/local/mysql/share/charsets/'
my_stat: error: Got errno: 2 from stat
run_plugin_auth: info: using plugin mysql_native_password
native_password_auth_client: info: no password
native_password_auth_client: info: IO layer change in progress...
ssl_do: info: ssl: 0x2823e50 timeout: 0
ssl_do: info: SSL connection succeeded
ssl_do: info: Using cipher: 'AES256-GCM-SHA384'
ssl_do: info: Peer certificate:
ssl_do: info:    subject: '/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=Gandi Standard Wildcard SSL/CN=*.example-dot-com-equivalent-for.co.uk'
ssl_do: info:    issuer: '/C=FR/ST=Paris/L=Paris/O=Gandi/CN=Gandi Standard SSL CA 2'
ssl_do: info: no shared ciphers!
native_password_auth_client: info: IO layer change done!
ssl_verify_server_cert: info: Server hostname in cert: *.example-dot-com-equivalent-for.co.uk
run_plugin_auth: info: authenticate_user returned CR_ERROR
run_plugin_auth: info: res=0
mysql_real_connect: error: message: 2026/HY000 (SSL connection error: SSL certificate validation failure)
end_server: info: Net:
main: info: Shutting down: infoflag: 3  print_info: 1
```

Note specifically that the `Server name` value matches the `CN` value.

The certificate is valid for the given hostname and is not expired, as verified by `openssl s_client -connect host.example-dot-com-equivalent-for.co.uk:443 -verify_return_error < /dev/null`. The "X509v3 Subject Alternative Name" field contains "DNS:*.example-dot-com-equivalent-for.co.uk, DNS:example-dot-com-equivalent-for.co.uk"

The whole certificate chain is in the file pointed to by the server's `ssl-cert` configuration, as [recommended elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22228434/96588). "USERTrust RSA Certification Authority" is in the client's /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt and /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.trust.crt. I tried adding `--ssl-ca=/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` to the command, but that didn't change anything.

The question ends up being: **Do MySQL/MariaDB clients support wildcard certificates? If they do, is something wrong with my connection?**

Original client:

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.21-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

Debug client:

```
$ ./client/mysql --version
./client/mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.56-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

Server:

```
# rpm -q mariadb
mariadb-5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
```

Posted to unix.SE rather than dba.SE because the problem may well be with the SSL libraries rather than the client.

Answer (score 2):

The MariaDB client libraries did not support wildcard certificates until [MariaDB 10.1.23](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13102).

Percona-Server's client library started supporting wildcard in [Percona Server 5.7.18-16](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/LATEST/release-notes/Percona-Server-5.7.18-16.html) and [Percona Server 5.6.36-82.1](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.6/release-notes/Percona-Server-5.6.36-82.1.html)

For both MariaDB and Percona-Server client libraries that support this feature, OpenSSL 1.0.2+ is additionally required for this support for the underlying `x509_check_host` function

Upstream MySQL clients as of 5.7.22  and 8.0.11 do not support wildcard certificates.

This applies just to libmysqlclient.so (libperconaserverclient.so) based clients.  SSL Wildcard support for other connectors (e.g. JDBC, Go, etc.) that do not wrap the mysql C API will depend on the particular implementation.